# checkbox always bind to false even if it is checked asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

i have created a list of model binder with checkbox  that is supposed to handle my forms  but when i post to controller it always set checkbox to false even if it is checked on client side, any help?

my model

```
   public class RoleCheckbox
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool ischecked { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class UsersNew
{
    public IList<RoleCheckbox> Roles { get; set; }
    [Required,MaxLength(128)]
    public string username { get; set; }
    [Required,DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string password { get; set; }
    [Required,MaxLength(256),DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string email { get; set; }

}
```

client code

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Roles</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Roles.Count; i++)
            {
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    @Html.Hidden("Roles[" +i +"].id",Model.Roles[i].id)
                    <label for="Roles_@(i)_ischecked">
                        @Html.CheckBox("Roles[" +i+ "].id",Model.Roles[i].ischecked)
                        @Model.Roles[i].name
                    </label>
                </li>

            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

my method

```
HttpPost,ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult New(UsersNew form)
    {

        var user = new User();
        syncRole(form.Roles, user.Roles);

        if (Database.Session.Query<User>().Any(u => u.username == form.username))
            ModelState.AddModelError("username", "username must be unique");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(form);

        user.email = form.email;
        user.username = form.username;
        user.SetPassword(form.password);
        Database.Session.Save(user);
        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
```

Comment: Show your model and the method your posting to. This is not the way to generate a checkbox (and is your `id` property really a `boolean`?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@Html.CheckBox()`, and the preferred `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` methods are for binding to `bool` properties. They generate a checkbox input with a value of true and a hidden input with a value of false. You attempting to bind it to property `id` and the value of `true` or `false` cannot be bound to an `int`. In any case, you already have a hidden input for property `id`, so the value of the checkbox is ignored (the `DefaultModelBinder` only reads the first form value matching a property name).

The value of your `ischecked` is always `false` because you never submit any value for it so its just its default value

Always use the stronlgly typed `***For()` methods, and bind the checkbox to the `bool` property. Your view should be

```
<ul class="list-group">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Roles.Count; i++)
    {
        <li class="list-group-item">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Roles[i].id)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Roles[i].ischecked)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Roles[i].ischecked, Model[i].name)
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Note that the `name` property will not be submitted unless you also include `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Roles[i].name)`

In the POST method you can then get the ID's of the selected roles using

```
IEnumerable<int> selected = model.Roles.Where(x => x.ischecked).Select(x => x.id);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was taking off the value="xxx" tag.  Then it functioned normally.  (Weird, I know.)